# How to review a question that ask for "Can anyone explain me the code"?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, triage

I was reviewing **Triage** and there were lot of questions that needed **help in understanding their code**.

I have read the guidelines on StackOverflow and could not figure out if to `flag` such questions or not.

And if to flag it, then which one to use of the following :

- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based
- Any other

Let me know of the appropriate action so that it may reduce false/incorrect flagging and may help in moderators reducing the noise.

Comment: I think you may be looking for off topic _why doesn't this code work?_.